# Usability Study of opening links in a new browser window

Tags: browser, usability, usability-testing

I hope this isn't too off topic for programming, but I'm sure lots of you would like more information when dealing with clients or managers on this topic.
I'm looking for actual usability testing & research into opening browser links in a new window.
I'm aware of all the reasons why it's a bad idea, but that's not what I'm looking for.
I'm also not looking for 'Jakob Nielson Says so', that won't cut it with my audience.

Cheers.
Murray.

Comment: Maybe better suited for ux.se?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to back up every design decision that you make with a relevant usability study or research paper, you won't be able to get much done.

If you've worn out Jacob Nielson, you could try Johan Petersson
http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/03/target-blank/

When dealing with your type of audience who just don't get it, the following has some good points: http://000fff.org/design-discussion-principles-how-to-get-your-client-to-love-your-design/

It's important to look at the goals of your manager or client who wants you to implement the "open in new window" functionality; they are not stupid, they are probably trying to e.g. keep users on the original site - if you gently point out the fact that the new window doesn't have the back button enabled in all(?) browsers such that it prevents users navigating back to your site, they might come around.

If not, and they have greater authority over the design, you'll have to go with their decision - it could be reversed later if you can show a real world example of it leading the user astray, or if your stats show that the user doesn't return after a new-window exit.

Answer (score 1):

Cracking open "Research-Based Web Design & Usability Guidelines", I see a few studies that could help you. Section "7.1: Provide Navigational Options" cites several sources, which I've copied below. It should be noted however that the strength of the findings was rated only 2 out of 5.

The book itself is free (funded by US tax dollars) and available here: http://www.usability.gov/guidelines/

- Detweiler, M.C. & Omanson, R.C. (1996). Ameritech Web Page User
  Interface Standards and Design Guidelines. Ameritech (now SBC).
- Lynch, P.J. & Horton, S. (2002). Web Style Guide (2nd Edition). New
  Haven, CO: Yale University Press. Retrieved November 2005, from
  http://www.webstyleguide.com/ index.html?/contents.html.
- Spool, J.M., Scanlon, T., Schroeder, W., Snyder, C., & DeAngelo, T.
  (1997). Web Site Usability: A Designer’s Guide. North Andover, MA:
  User Interface Engineering.
- Zimmerman, D.E., Slater, M., & Kendall, P. (2001). Risk communication
  and a usability case study: Implications for Web site design.
  Proceedings of the IEEE International Professional Communication
  Conference, 445-452.

Answer (score 0):

Google was unable to provide me with any research results related to opening browser links in a new window.

I would assume that the answer depends on the context and scenarios.  For instance, when browsing the Washington Post online, I like the linearity of the browsing experience with link replacing the content of the current window, but when using Google Docs, I like that the main page opens a new window whenever I choose to create a new document or open an existing document.

You may want to consider convincing the client to perform usability testing to guide the decision.